# Checking fixed height RichTextBox for overflow

Tags: wpf

I am working for an editor using WPF 3.5. I am using fixed Height RichTextBox for it. When rtb is full or Overflow I want to increase the height of rtb by one page. Can any one help me how to check rtb is full or overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it may help you to resolve the problem.. Check the below tag

[Measure String inside RichTextBox Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364970/measure-string-inside-richtextbox-control)