# Size RichTextBox according to contents

Tags: c#, winforms

This code automatically sizes a RichTextBox according to it's contents.  I'm having issues, especially with tables.  `\t` may be ignored.  I tried a managed solution, now I'm trying platform invoke.   Current Output:

[image]

```
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetTextExtentPoint32(IntPtr hdc, string lpString, int cbString, out SIZE lpSize);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);

    [StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SIZE
    {
        public int cx;
        public int cy;

        public SIZE(int cx, int cy)
        {
            this.cx = cx;
            this.cy = cy;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Form form = new Form();
        RichTextBox rtfBox = new RichTextBox();

        rtfBox.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil Arial;}}\viewkind4\uc1\trowd\trgaph100\cellx1000\cellx2000\pard\intbl\lang1033\f0\fs20  hi\cell  bye\cell\row\intbl  one\cell  two\cell\row\pard\par}";
        rtfBox.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;

        string sInput = "hi\t bye\t\n";// one\t two\t\n";
        SIZE CharSize;

        form.Controls.Add(rtfBox);

        IntPtr hdc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);//Context for entire screen
        GetTextExtentPoint32(hdc, sInput, sInput.Length, out CharSize);

        rtfBox.Width = CharSize.cx;
        rtfBox.Height = CharSize.cy;

        form.Visible = false;

        form.ShowDialog();
    }
```

(Note, for simplicity this is a console application with a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you looked at the [`ContentsResized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.contentsresized.aspx) event? Add the following method to be called when the event fires:

```
private void richTextBox_ContentsResized(object sender, ContentsResizedEventArgs e)
{
    var richTextBox = (RichTextBox) sender;
    richTextBox.Width = e.NewRectangle.Width;
    richTextBox.Height = e.NewRectangle.Height;
}
```

When the RTF content is changed (using [`Rtf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf)), the `RichTextBox` should be resized to match its contents. Make sure you also set the [`WordWrap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.wordwrap) property to `false`.

---

I've tried it with your table example and it does appear to work (albeit with a little offset, which you could possibly solve by adding a few pixels of width to the adjusted size - not sure why that happens):

[image]

**P.Brian.Mackey EDIT**
This answer worked for me.  To clarify, here's the final code including border fix:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        string sInput = "hi\t bye\t\n";// one\t two\t\n";
        SIZE CharSize;
        Form form = new Form();
        RichTextBox rtfBox = new RichTextBox();
        rtfBox.ContentsResized += (object sender, ContentsResizedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            var richTextBox = (RichTextBox)sender;
            richTextBox.Width = e.NewRectangle.Width;
            richTextBox.Height = e.NewRectangle.Height;
            rtfBox.Width += rtfBox.Margin.Horizontal + SystemInformation.HorizontalResizeBorderThickness;
        };

        rtfBox.WordWrap = false;
        rtfBox.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;

        rtfBox.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil Arial;}}\viewkind4\uc1\trowd\trgaph100\cellx1000\cellx2000\pard\intbl\lang1033\f0\fs20  hi\cell  bye\cell\row\intbl  one\cell  two\cell\row\pard\par}";

        form.Controls.Add(rtfBox);
        form.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: @HansPassant: does it work if you turn word wrap off on the rich text box?

Comment: No.  Not sure why you see something else.

Comment: @HansPassant: it's a mystery to me as well! (Win7 x64, .Net 4).

Comment: This is the correct answer. The little offset is due to the missing `richTextBox.Margin.Horizontal` + `SystemInformation.HorizontalResizeBorderThickness` + `SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarThumbWidth`

Comment: @banging - That is great info.  Although, I don't need that HorizontalScrollBarThumbWidth because scrollbars are disabled.

Comment: I do not find the event. I am using RichTextBox Class (System.Windows.Controls)

Answer (score 2):

It's much easier to use [GetPreferredSize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2365687/603828), as described in this answer.  Then you don't need to wait for a ContentsResized event,

Answer (score 0):

What about the Height ?
I added

```
richTextBox.Height += richTextBox.Margin.Vertical +  
SystemInformation.VerticalResizeBorderThickness;
```

at the end.

It also looks like a good candidate for an extension method :

```
static public class RichTextBoxResizer {  
    static public void ResizeToContents(this RichTextBox richTextBox, ContentsResizedEventArgs e) {  
        richTextBox.Width = e.NewRectangle.Width;  
        richTextBox.Height = e.NewRectangle.Height;  

        richTextBox.Width += richTextBox.Margin.Horizontal +  
            SystemInformation.HorizontalResizeBorderThickness +  
            SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarThumbWidth;  

        richTextBox.Height += richTextBox.Margin.Vertical +  
            SystemInformation.VerticalResizeBorderThickness;  
    }   

    static public void ResizeToContentsHorizontally(this RichTextBox richTextBox, ContentsResizedEventArgs e) {
        richTextBox.Width = e.NewRectangle.Width;

        richTextBox.Width += richTextBox.Margin.Horizontal +
            SystemInformation.HorizontalResizeBorderThickness +
            SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarThumbWidth;
    }

    static public void ResizeToContentsVertically(this RichTextBox richTextBox, ContentsResizedEventArgs e) {
        richTextBox.Height = e.NewRectangle.Height;

        richTextBox.Height += richTextBox.Margin.Vertical +
            SystemInformation.VerticalResizeBorderThickness;
    }
}
```

So the event sink looks like :

```
private void rtfBox_ContentsResized(object sender, ContentsResizedEventArgs e) {  
    RichTextBox rtb = (RichTextBox)sender;  
    rtb.ResizeToContents(e);  
}
```