# RichTextBox Multi_Line does not work at all

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I saw a nice codes "RichTextBox Cell in a DataGridView" from some place else (thanks it is nice). 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31823/RichTextBox-Cell-in-a-DataGridView

And made some changes using some other's codes (thanks again).

Full codes of mine are here.

http://cfile235.uf.daum.net/attach/23452047578DA97C278673

My data is pretty simple;

```
    static dynamic myArray1 = new string[] { "1 The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog", "2 abc"};
    static dynamic myArray2 = new string[] { "3 abc", "4 abc" };
    static dynamic myArray = new string[][] { myArray1, myArray2 };
```

Question "How can I make it multi-lined ?".

This is what I have.

[image]

This is what I want to make.

[image]

Yes, I know how to handle it when I am in normal "TextBox".

But, It is useless when I am in "RichTextBox".

Please, Help..

Regards

Comment: It has multiline property itself : `public override bool Multiline { get; set; }` see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.multiline(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks. That is a good point. But, it is not working at all. Do you have any idea what do I have to do ?

Comment: Check this one  out- `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906932/size-richtextbox-according-to-contents`

Comment: @Vicky Thanks comment. my "RichTextBoxColumn" does not have any kind of events.