# vb.net textbox / richtextbox GetPreferredSize not working

Tags: vb.net, winforms, richtextbox

I have a winforms RichTextBox and TextBox (trying both). As I type text, I want the box to get bigger vertically (or smaller vertically) so that all the text is viewable.

I am using the following code in the RichTextBox TextChanged event:

```
RTB.Height = RTB.GetPreferredSize(New Size(RTB.Width, 0)).Height
```

This code works in most situations apart from one - when you put in a single word (without spaces) which is larger than the width of the box. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the following answer already on Stackoverflow! Just had to search better ...

```
Private Sub rtb_ContentsResized(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ContentsResizedEventArgs) Handles txtQuestion.ContentsResized
    Dim h = e.NewRectangle.Height, w = e.NewRectangle.Width
    h = Math.Max(h, sender.Font.Height)
    h = Math.Min(h, Me.ClientSize.Height - 10 - sender.Top)
    h += sender.Height - sender.ClientSize.Height + 1
    sender.Height = h
End Sub
```

from

[Measure String inside RichTextBox Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364970/measure-string-inside-richtextbox-control)

Answer (score 0):

Try experimenting with the RTB min and max size properties.

Sounds like setting a max width may address your issue.

Comment: Unfortuinately `RTB.MaximumSize = New Size(RTB.Width, 0)` before setting the height doesn't help :(

Comment: Setting max width will constrain RTB width so that the long word will cause RTB to grow in height instead of just getting wider. Set max/min (and maybe WordWrap) properties at design time, or perhaps in the form's after resize event to control size increases.